# Item position by css?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css. Sorry this too easy question, maybe stupit. vid2 under the vid1, it's ok. But, I try to put vid3 rigth of to vid1. But It isn't working.

Actually, I am tring to do something like that;

index.html;

[vid1]   [vid3]  [vid5]

[vid2]   [vid4]  [vid6]

Could you help me to fix code. Thank you.

```css
.vid1
    {
    position: absolute; overflow:hidden; left: 10px; top: 10px; z-index:0;
    }
    .vid2
    {
    position : absolute; overflow:hidden; left::20px; top:180px;  z-index:0;
    }
    .vid3
    {
    position : absolute; overflow:hidden; left::200px; top:10px;  z-index:0;
    }
```

```html
<iframe class="vid1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r9dsH8H-4P8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="vid2"  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/i7sxqaC062A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="vid3"  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YeJQBbtjgK8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? Also you have a typo in the left attribute. You have used double colon marks like `left:: 200px`. It should be `left:200px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you not to use `position: absolute;` because it will be too messy if you change the display/window size and also your code will be too complex to work on later.

What i would suggest instead is to **go column by column using relative positioning**.
Like this:

column-1     column-2     column-3

[vid1]           [vid3]           [vid5]

[vid2]           [vid4]           [vid6]

Here's your code with the above relative positioning modifications:

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

iframe:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.column:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.col_1_of_3 {
  width: 32.66%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .col_1_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">

    <!--COLUMN 1-->
    <div class="column col_1_of_3">
      <iframe id="vid1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r9dsH8H-4P8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <iframe id="vid3" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/i7sxqaC062A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <!--COLUMN 2-->
    <div class="column col_1_of_3">
      <iframe id="vid2" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YeJQBbtjgK8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <iframe id="vid4" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r9dsH8H-4P8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Run the above Code Snippet in Full Page and verify the layout yourself. The advantage of this code is that, this is easily scalable to add more videos in the same manner specified by you and is also responsive - to work with small devices like tablets and phones.

You can always rely on this simple grid generator tool: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com which generates elegant responsive CSS grid codes.

Let me know if this helps, also feel free to ask questions if you find something ambiguous on my answer.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: Can I ask you a last question. If I want to put a space in left side on the page. 
Where should I make changes?

Comment: @tunc
To add a space on the left side of the page, edit this code:
`.column:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}`
To have a value greater than 0px, like this:
`.column:first-child {
    margin-left: 100px;
}`

Comment: @tunc, if you are thinking about centering the columns then do not add space on the left side, edit this code: `.row {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}` to this: `.row {
    width: 950px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}`
This will keep the columns in the center of the page no matter what the display size is.

Comment: Thanks. I tried .column:first-child { margin-left: 100px; }. But it doesn't change.

Comment: @tunc, here's the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cugzz5ry/ with `.column:first-child { margin-left: 200px; }`

Answer (score 2):

You should change the code `left :: 200px;` to `left : 200px;`, Then you can avoid position absolute to get 3 in a row..

Answer (score 0):

CSS for `.vid3` as below

```
.vid3
{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
float: right;
right: 700;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Used this I think help for you.

```css
.video{width:300px; float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="video">
<iframe class="vid1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r9dsH8H-4P8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="vid2" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/i7sxqaC062A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="video">
<iframe class="vid3" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YeJQBbtjgK8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe class="vid4" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YeJQBbtjgK8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```